# Cumcount en nueva columna a partir de condición

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero crear una nueva columna en mi dataframe de Pandas que cuente cuántos días han pasado desde que el valor en otra columna es uno determinado. El objetivo en este ejemplo es contar cuántos días han pasado desde que un jugador ha marcado un gol. Éste sería el resultado que busco, con la nueva columna "Días desde gol" que se generaría a partir del valor "Sí" en la columna "Gol":

```
      Jugador     Fecha           Gol      Días desde gol
0     John        11-7-2022       No       0
1     Charles     11-7-2022       Sí       1
2     John        12-7-2022       Sí       1
3     Charles     12-7-2022       No       2
4     John        13-7-2022       No       2
5     Charles     13-7-2022       No       3
6     John        14-7-2022       No       3
7     Charles     14-7-2022       No       4
8     Peter       15-7-2022       No       0
9     John        15-7-2022       Sí       1
10    Charles     16-7-2022       No       5
11    Peter       16-7-2022       Sí       1
12    John        16-7-2022       No       2
```

Estoy muy cerca de conseguirlo con este código:

```
blocks = df['Gol'].ge("Sí").groupby(df['Jugador']).cumsum()
df['Días desde gol'] = df.groupby([df['Jugador'],blocks]).cumcount()
```

Sin embargo, el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
      Jugador     Fecha           Gol      Días desde gol
0     John        11-7-2022       No       0
1     Charles     11-7-2022       Sí       0
2     John        12-7-2022       Sí       0
3     Charles     12-7-2022       No       1
4     John        13-7-2022       No       1
5     Charles     13-7-2022       No       2
6     John        14-7-2022       No       2
7     Charles     14-7-2022       No       3
8     Peter       15-7-2022       No       0
9     John        15-7-2022       Sí       0
10    Charles     16-7-2022       No       4
11    Peter       16-7-2022       Sí       0
12    John        16-7-2022       No       1
```

El problema es que necesito que en el caso de ser "Sí", ya se contabilice como 1 y no como 0 y a partir de ahí, el siguiente "No" sería ya 2, etc. ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo podría modificar mi código? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías agregar el código con el que generas el DataFrame, o en su defecto un código para generar un DataFrame de ejemplo por favor? De ese modo me será posible saber la estructura de tu DataFrame y buscar así una forma de lograrlo.

Comment: Al final pensé un poco tu pregunta y creo entender la estructura de tu dataframe. Sin embargo, la proxima te pido que des un código que genere el DataFrame. Tuve que transcribir algunos datos del DataFrame en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota: No se si este es el modo más rapido. Sin embargo, espero que sirva a tu proposito.

En lugar de usar groupby, podes usar una función y el método apply:

**Edición** Según el comentario del OP, esperaba que el contador se reinicie al alcanzar 3. Esto fue implementado en el código.

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([("john", "No"),
                   ("charles", "Sí"),
                   ("john", "Sí"),
                   ("charles", "No"),
                   ("john", "No"),
                   ("charles", "No"),
                   ("john", "No"),
                   ("charles", "No"),
                   ("peter", "No"),
                   ("john", "Sí"),
                   ("charles", "No"),
                   ("peter", "Sí"),
                   ("john", "No")],
                  columns=["Jugador", "Gol"])

from collections import defaultdict

gol_dict = defaultdict(int)

def gol_counter(row):
    if(row.Gol == "Sí"):
        gol_dict[row.Jugador] = 1
    elif(row.Jugador in gol_dict):
        if(gol_dict[row.Jugador] >= 3):
            gol_dict[row.Jugador] = 1
        else:
            gol_dict[row.Jugador] += 1

    return gol_dict[row.Jugador]
    

df["dias_desde_gol"] = df.apply(gol_counter, axis=1)

print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
    Jugador Gol  dias_desde_gol
0      john  No               0
1   charles  Sí               1
2      john  Sí               1
3   charles  No               2
4      john  No               2
5   charles  No               3
6      john  No               3
7   charles  No               4
8     peter  No               0
9      john  Sí               1
10  charles  No               5
11    peter  Sí               1
12     john  No               2
```

###### Explicación

El plan sería que por cada fila:

- Si gol es igual a "Sí": Agregamos el jugador al diccionario con un valor de 1.
- Si no si ya el jugador está en el diccionario, le sumamos uno al valor.

Sin importar el resultado de los condicionales, se retorna el valor correspondiente al jugador visitado. Al usarse un defaultdict(int), el valor predeterminado en el diccionario es 0. Lo que significa que si el jugador no está en el diccionario, se devuelve 0.

Comment: La solución es perfecta, funciona consiguiendo exactamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada compa c:

Comment: Sé que es otra pregunta distinta pero tiene bastante que ver y no sé si sería conveniente abrir otro hilo por este detalle... Imagina que quiero que se sumen a partir del "Sí" pero quiero que la secuencia en lugar de ser 1,2,3,4,5,6 y así hasta el próximo "Sí" fuese 1,2,3,1,2,3 y se reiniciase en el siguiente "Sí". Es decir, como un rango del 1 al 3 en lugar de siempre +1 a partir del "Sí"

Comment: Agrega un condicional dentro del elif. Si el valor del jugador es mayor o igual a 3, reestableces el valor a 1, en caso contrario, le sumas 1.

Comment: Llevo un buen rato intentando meter un if dentro del elif pero algo estoy haciendo mal (soy muy novato en Python). Intento:

`def gol_counter(row):
    if(row.Gol == "Sí"):
        gol_dict[row.Jugador] = 1
    elif(row.Jugador in gol_dict):
        gol_dict[row.Jugador] += 1
        if(row.Jugador in gol_dict >= 3):
            gol_dict[row.Jugador] = 1
        else:
            gol_dict[row.Jugador] += 1
             
    return gol_dict[row.Jugador]`

Pero recibo error `'>=' not supported between instances of 'collections.defaultdict' and 'int'`. Algo estoy haciendo fatal :(

Comment: Hola! Edité la respuesta, espero te sirva! Recuerda que cuando haces condicionales, es como hablar con una persona. Eso te ayudará a poder pensar mejor tus condicionales.

Comment: Fenomenal. Mil gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada nokvk c: